# is there any way to install libxml2 on windows?

Tags: python, lxml, libxml2

I'm working with a legacy project, and I need to install a libxml2 compatible with python 3.X

I need to use lxml 4.1.1, I tried to work with Christoph Gohlke's Window binaries https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml , but he doesn't have the version that I need

I have also seen the libxml2 at http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/python/ , but it's only compatible with Python 2.X

I already tried newer versions of lxml, but it does not work for me

And trying to install the version that I need with pip gets me this error:

```
Could not find function xmlCheckVersion in library libxml2. Is libxml2 installed?
```

there is any work around for this?

Comment: Take a look at [lxml docs](https://lxml.de/installation.html)

Comment: I had seen the lxml docs before, but all they say about how to install the older version that I need it, it to firstly install libxml2, so I'm kinda in a loop

Comment: So, take a look [here](https://www.zlatkovic.com/projects/libxml/index.html)

Comment: Can't you install 4.1.1 from PyPI? https://pypi.org/project/lxml/4.1.1/

Comment: i tried to download directly from PyPI, but still requires libxml2 to install

Comment: Same problem here! On Windows I cannot get LibXML2 to 'install'. Tried this https://pages.lip6.fr/Jean-Francois.Perrot/XML-Int/Session1/WinLibxml.html by downloading 64bit http://xmlsoft.org/sources/win32/64bit/ and putting /bin files (exe+dll) into directory then adding directory to PATH but same issue...  "canot open include file: 'libxml/xpath.h' with other issues as well... Tried installing the WHL files but as mentioned elsewhere libxml2 are C/C++... A note here is I'm trying with Python2.7 but have no issue running #pip install -r requirements.txt on a linux VM. Any pointers...?